# How to use "normal PHP" in symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I have a php code where I uses sql connections and creating some results. But i don't use any symphony related codes. Where should I deploy those kids of data. At the moment It gives me following errors. But When i run the same code in my localhost WAMP server it works fine.

```
404 | Not Found | sfError404Exception
Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/race/getitemnames.php?eventid=1" (/).
stack trace

    at ()
    in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/controller/sfFrontWebController.class.php line 44 ...
                  if (empty($moduleName) || empty($actionName))
                  {
                    throw new sfError404Exception(sprintf('Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "%s" (%s/%s).', $request->getPathInfo(), $moduleName, $actionName));
                  }
                  // make the first request
    at sfFrontWebController->dispatch()
    in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/util/sfContext.class.php line 170 ...
    at sfContext->dispatch()
    in SF_ROOT_DIR/web/index.php line 7 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **RewriteRule**.

Comment: where can i find it?. I dont know anything about symphony. I just need to add my codes to the same server.

Comment: @dinesh Try to find a `.htaccess` file in your symfony web dir.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that you'll have to place the external script somewhere beneath your web root, which I assume will be SYMFONY_PROJECT_DIR/web/race/getitemnames.php.

Ideally, you should not put these kind of scripts inside a symfony project. They may open up your project for security risks and other unforeseen behaviours.

I'd suggest to only have your symfony project run at that particular vhost, and if you need to run another framework/script/whatever create a **separate** virtual host for it with a **different** web root. For example have your symfony project run from www.mydomain.com, and create a separate host scripts.mydomain.com which will serve stand-alone scripts.

If it is a simple script, you should also investigate if you could rewrite it to run from a symfony action. If possible, create a new module and/or action in your symfony project that executes your script's code. Add a route to it, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Also check wether you have set

`<directory "path/to/project">`

Allowoverride All

</directory>

for your vhost on apache.